# How to find the minimal element of each column in a two-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
import random
x =[[random.randint(1,10) for j in range(5)] for i in range(4)]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        print("%4d" % (x[i][j]), end="")
    print(end='\n')
```

I need to find minimal element of each column in a  two-dimensional array and add them in a new array(one-dimensional array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to apply `min` to each column of data:

```
import random
x =[[random.randint(1,10) for j in range(5)] for i in range(4)]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        print("%4d" % (x[i][j]), end="")
    print(end='\n')

print([min(x[i][j] for i in range(4)) for j in range(5)])
```

Sample output:

```
   8   1   7   6   9
   9   2   8   6   8
  10   5   3   3   5
   1   9   7  10   9

[1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.min(arr_name, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use min on each column and list comprehension.

```
x_new = [min(x_i) for x_i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into numpy() and specifically [np.min()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html). The code can then be:

```
# Convert 'x' to np array-
x_np = np.asarray(x)

# Sanity check-
x_np
'''
array([[ 8,  7, 10,  8,  8],
       [ 6,  6,  3,  6,  6],
       [ 9,  4,  2,  8,  3],
       [ 2,  4,  5,  3,  4]])
'''

# Minimum elements by squashing the columns-
np.min(x_np, axis = 1)
# array([7, 3, 2, 2])

# Minimum elements by squashing the rows-
np.min(x_np, axis = 0)
# array([2, 4, 2, 3, 3])
```